# QT window not showed in mission control

Tags: macos, qt, window

I've created a qt application for mac but when I launch mission control, the application is not displayed, what I've to do for that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you mean LaunchPad. If that is what you want move or copy your application to the folder /Applications

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my app was working fine but after switching to mission control the window disappeared. In my case I made a mistake by calling `exec()` method on the main dialog and not on `QApplication`. If you did the same, then calling `show()` on the dialog and `exec()` on the application will fix this issue.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainDialog dialog;
  dialog.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the window modality to `Qt::ApplicationModal` may also result in the "vanishing" window behaviour. If you are using Designer Form (`.ui`) files, look for an entry similar to the following and remove it

```
<property name="windowModality">
 <enum>Qt::ApplicationModal</enum>
</property>
```

Alternatively you can set the window modality of the main window in Designer GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I set WindowModality on main application window

```
main_window->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModality::WindowModal);
```